# What Heroku plan do I need to process Stripe Payments?

Tags: ios, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm working on an iOS app and needed to deploy a very simple web-app for processing Stripe payments, so I deployed a Ruby Sinatra app for free on Heroku.

It's up and running and seems to be working great (the iOS app is not in production yet though), but I'm worried about scalability and know very little about web hosting. Is the free plan good enough for my use case? Again, the web-app does absolutely nothing besides respond to a POST request that processes Stripe payments.

I saw the free plan says "Sleeps after 30 min of inactivity". What does that mean? When it sleeps will it not be able to process payments? It also says "Uses an account based pool of free dyno hours". What does that mean? What is a dyno? And finally, it says "1 web/1 worker". What does that mean? What is a worker? Sorry for the lack of knowledge, just have no background in web hosting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still run Stripe on the free account without any issues.

If your app is not doing anything, it will sleep, otherwise if there is activity going it won't.

Comment: and what is the consequence when it "sleeps"?

Comment: I think the main consequence of your app sleeping is that it will take a few seconds longer to spool up again when it receives another request.

Comment: okay thanks. just don't want that shit to sleep forever ya know?

Comment: You can ping it, with some uptime checker and it might never go to sleep. But heroku is changing its rules and will allow almost free hosting if you just have one app.

Comment: How bad is it when it goes to sleep @knuxus ?

Comment: Its not bad at all, from sleeping state your app could be running in less than 30 secs. depending of how heavy it is of course.

Comment: hmm.. 30 secs is actually kind of a long time to process a payment. It's extremely lightweight though.